# modulenotfounderror no module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Windows 10, CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Duo CPU T6600 @ 2.2GHz (2 CPUs) ~2.2GHz. RAM: 4GB. Video card: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series.

I uninstalled everything and then

I installed Python 3.6 and Tensorflow==1.10.0. When I do `import tensorflow`, I get this error.

> modulenotfounderror no module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

I can install whichever Python/Tensorflow version you want. I just want to use Tensorflow. I saw similar issues, but none of them seems to be solving my issue.

I know there are many similar questions on github/stackoverflow, but none of them seems to help me.

Comment: you can use tensorflow==2 with python 3.6 .. they are compatible

Comment: I think from Tensorflow 1.6, CPU need to support AVX instructions, and I have 10 year old CPU maybe.

Comment: I think I solved it by using Python==3.6, Tensorflow==1.5, protobuf==3.6.0

Comment: @JohnBott: Can you please clarify if using `Tensorflow Version 1.15` resolved your issue or using `Tensorflow Version 1.5` resolved your issue. You mentioned `1.5` but just wanted to confirm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning the Answer here for the benefit of the Community.

Issue is resolved by using `Python==3.6`, `Tensorflow==1.5`, `protobuf==3.6.0`.